# Get maximum depth of selected node in DOM using jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom

I would like to count count maximum 'depth' of the DOM tree structure (the length of the longest branch of a tree given its root). For example:

```
<div class="group level0" id="group1">
    <div class="group level1" id="group2">
        <div class="group level2" id="group3">
            <div class="group level3">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="group level1">
        <div class="group level2">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For example result for `div#group1` would be 3. Result for `div#group2` would be 2 and result for `div#group3` would be 1.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you only want to trace the DOM tree down through elements with the same class as the provided "root" element?

Comment: How do you expect that result be 3 when your #group1 have 5 descendant divs?

Comment: @undefined The depth is 3. OP wants the length of the longest branch of a tree given its root.

Comment: The question is'nt really clear? Is it the longest tree, based on class, just the ones with ID, the first child, and a number of other possibilities.

Comment: I don't want to count all children of the same class of the selected node. I want to return the maximum depth of the selected node in the tree structure.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas I got the point. Misread the question.

Comment: I will modify my question to be more clear

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here:

```
var calcDepth = function ( root ) {
    var $children = $( root ).children();
    var depth = 0;

    while ( $children.length > 0 ) {
        $children = $children.children();
        depth += 1;
    }

    return depth;
};
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/WqXy9/

```
calcDepth( $('#group1')[0] ) // => 3
calcDepth( $('#group2')[0] ) // => 2
```

Comment: I'll upvote this one, even though it seems strange to get the jQuery object, turn it into a plain JS object, pass it to the funtion and then make it into a jQuery object, again ?

Comment: The question title states that he only wants to follow elements with the same class; this function does not take that into account. It also assumes only one child node at each level of the DOM. Sibling nodes with longer depth won't be accounted for.

Comment: @adeneo I like to keep direct references to DOM elements, and then wrap them in jQuery objects when neccesary. The idea is to do `var elem = $('#elem')[0];` on page-init, and then use `elem`, and `$(elem)` throughout the application. That's just what I'm used to doing. One can pass a jQuery object direcctly, of course, if he likes.

Comment: @jackwanders "*elements with the same class*" - I'll update my answer. *** "*It also assumes only one child node at each level of the DOM*" - No, I don't think it does. `.children()` will pass the entire sub-tree.

Comment: You're right about `.children()`, my mistake. As for using `$(elem)` throughout your code, this is very inefficient, as you'd constantly be processing `elem` into a jQuery object. Better to have it stored as a variable like `$elem` for re-use.

Comment: @jackwanders The performance penalty of instantiating a jQuery object is a couple of micro-seconds, which is negligible. Having lots of `$(elem)` throughout the code **does not** hurt performance.

Comment: this function will return wrong result if there is another tag wrapped around target elements. example: http://jsfiddle.net/WqXy9/1/

Comment: @PrimozRome I don't understand. Don't you want the result to be 3 in that case? You mentioned in your title (before) that you only want elements of the same class (in this case "group") to count?

Comment: @PrimozRome I've rolled my answer back to its original state. Now, the depth is calculated regardless of class-names.

Answer (score 1):

This function will find the maximum depth through the DOM tree from a given `root`, tracing the tree only through nodes with a specific `class`:

```
function getDepth(root, className) {
    var children = root.children('.' + className),
        maxDepth = 0;

    if (children.length === 0) {
        return maxDepth;
    } else {
        children.each(function() {
            var depth = 1 + getDepth($(this), className);
            if (depth > maxDepth) {
                maxDepth = depth;
            }
        });
    }

    return maxDepth;
}

var root = $('#group1');
var className = 'group';

var depth = getDepth(root,className);​
```

Here's a demo with a slightly more complex DOM:

[**--- jsFiddle DEMO ---**](http://jsfiddle.net/upVFZ/)

Comment: this one will not work down to the leaves if there is another dom element in between searched elements. for example if a .group is wrapped in <section> tag then it will only count to here... example http://jsfiddle.net/PquP2/

Answer (score 0):

Here is non recursive solution:

```
function len(sel) {
    var depth = 0;
    $(sel + " :not(:has(*))").each(function() {
        var tmp = $(this).parentsUntil(sel).length + 1;
        if (tmp > depth) depth = tmp;
    });
    return depth;
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/f2REj/

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.fn.depth = function() {
    var children = jQuery(this).children();
    if (children.length === 0)
        return 0;
    else
    {
        var maxLength = 0;
        children.each(function()
        {
            maxLength = Math.max(jQuery(this).depth(), maxLength);
        });
        return 1 + maxLength;
    }
};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7Q3a9/